# graphQL and graphene: How to extract information from a graphQL query using graphene?

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python

I want to extract the line 'Unique protein chains: 1' from [this](https://www.rcsb.org/structure/5O6C) entry, using a graphQL query.

I know this is the query I want to use:

```
{
  entry(entry_id: "5O6C") {
    rcsb_entry_info {
      polymer_entity_count_protein
    }
  }
}
```

and I can see the output if I use the graphQL interface [here](http://data.rcsb.org/graphql/index.html?query=%7B%0A%20%20entry(entry_id%3A%20%225O6C%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20rcsb_entry_info%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20polymer_entity_count_protein%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A):

```
{
  "data": {
    "entry": {
      "rcsb_entry_info": {
        "polymer_entity_count_protein": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Has the information I want : "polymer_entity_count_protein": 1

I want to run this query through python so it can be fed into other pipelines (and also process multiple IDs).

I found graphene to be one library that will do graphQL queries, and this is the hello world example, which I can get to work on my machine:

```
import graphene

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    hello = graphene.String(name=graphene.String(default_value="world"))

    def resolve_hello(self, info, name):
        return name

schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
result = schema.execute('{ hello }')
print(result.data['hello']) # "Hello World"
```

I don't understand how to combine the two. Can someone show me how I edit my python code with the query of interest, so what's printed at the end is:

```
'506C  1'
```

I have seen some other examples/queries about graphene/graphQL: e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41345377/graphql-and-graphene); except I can't understand how to make my specific example work.

Based on answer below, I ran:

import graphene

```
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    # ResponseType needs to be the type of your response
    # the following line defines the return value of your query (ResponseType)  
    # and the inputType (graphene.String())
    entry = graphene.String(entry_id=graphene.String(default_value=''))

    def resolve_entry(self, info, **kwargs):
        id = kwargs.get('entry_id')
            # as you already have a working query you should enter the logic here   

schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
# not totally sure if the query needs to look like this, it also depends heavily on your response type
query = '{ entry(entry_id="506C"){rcsb_entry_info}'
result = schema.execute(query)
print("506C" + str(result.data.entry.rcsb_entry_info.polymer_entity_count_protein))
```

However, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "graphene_query_for_rcsb.py", line 18, in <module>
    print("506C" + str(result.data.entry.rcsb_entry_info.polymer_entity_count_protein))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'entry'
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you write the logic of the already working query you have in your question? Is it not using python/ graphene?

I'm not sure if I understood the question correctly but here's a general idea:

```
import graphene


class Query(graphene.ObjectType):

    # ResponseType needs to be the type of your response
    # the following line defines the return value of your query (ResponseType)  
    # and the inputType (graphene.String())
    entry = graphene.Field(ResponseType, entry_id=graphene.String()

    def resolve_entry(self, info, **kwargs):
        id = kwargs.get('entry_id')
        # as you already have a working query you should enter the logic here   

schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
# not totally sure if the query needs to look like this, it also depends heavily on your response type
query = '{ entry(entry_id="506C"){rcsb_entry_info}}'
result = schema.execute(query)
print("506C" + str(result.data.entry.rcsb_entry_info.polymer_entity_count_protein)
```

Here an example for a response type:
if you have the query

```
 # here TeamType is my ResponseType
get_team = graphene.Field(TeamType, id=graphene.Int())

    def resolve_get_team(self, info, **kwargs):
        id = kwargs.get('id')

        if id is not None:
             return Team.objects.get(pk=id)

        else:
            raise Exception();
```

the responseType is defined as:

```
class TeamType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Team
```

but you can also define a response type that is not based on a model:

```
class DeleteResponse(graphene.ObjectType):
    numberOfDeletedObject = graphene.Int(required=True)
    numberOfDeletedTeams = graphene.Int(required=False)
```

And your response type should look **something like** this:

```
class myResponse(graphene.ObjectType):
    rcsb_entry_info = graphne.Field(Polymer)


class Polymer(graphene.ObjectType):
    polymer_entity_count_protein = graphene.Int()
```

again this is not testet or anything and I don't really know what your response really is.

Comment: Could I ask more about the 'ResponseType'? when you say 'its the type of your response', do you mean it should be 'str' or something (or could you direct me to where the options for this are?)

Comment: I've amended my question to show you what I've tried extra, I've added in the code I used.

Comment: sorry I had a stuoid mistake in my answer. You need to add an additional `}` at the end of the query string. But still I'm not totally sure if that query string will work at all

Comment: With ResponseType you can specificly design what your query gives in response. For example if you have the query: `getPerson` you want to have a Person as response. That Person needs to be defined in a type. I'll add a more detailled example to my answer